# How to make a GridView with maxmimum size set to the containing DIV

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, html, styles

I want to fix the size of a GridView depending on the DIV containing it. I changed every possible attribute but nothing changes in the gridview. Here is the markup:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="height:100%">
<tr>
<td>
    <div style="width: 500px">
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                       AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                       DataSourceID="QuotationSQLDS" 
                       onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  
                       ForeColor="Black" Width="100%">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="8pt" />
                <Columns>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" 
                                     ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="description" 
                                     HeaderText="Description" 
                                     SortExpression="description" />
                </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Please help me out because I am about to kick my laptop. Thanks

Comment: What do you see? Put a border around the div

Comment: I see the div of the border just covering some part of the GridView.

Comment: your question is bit confusing. What you need to do here? Do you have divs with different widths and you need to set the width of gridview depending on the size of each div?

Comment: I have the markup that you see in the question. When the table is more than 500px it does not shrink to fit the dimension of the div but trespass its border (right side) so to see the whole table I need to horizontally scroll.

Comment: ok, try adding this styles to the div  height:auto; float:left;overflow:hidden;display:block;

Comment: Are there any CSS styles that the GridView may be inheriting? Try using F12 tools to see the actual attributes the GridView is using.

Comment: @huMpty duMpty: I added those attributes and instead of seeing the Gridview stretching I see just the columns  that fit inside the div area, the others disappeared (and there is not scrollbar)

Comment: @CiccioMiami : i have added a answer, try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing something like this

add class to both `gridview` and containing `div`

```
<div class="container" style="width: 500px">
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="gvData"
                       AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                       DataSourceID="QuotationSQLDS" 
                       onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  
                       ForeColor="Black">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="8pt" />
                <Columns>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" 
                                     ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id"/>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="description" 
                                     HeaderText="Description" 
                                     SortExpression="description" />
                </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

And use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var height = $('.container').height();
   $('.gvData').height(height);
});
```

and in your `.css`:

```
.container{height:auto; float:left;overflow:hidden;display:block;}
```

Comment: Same result as the one I obtained without script

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work if you are looking your grid view to be as broad as 500px.
Is it getting broader than that?

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I decrease the size of the DIV, let's say 200px, it does not change anything. That's what is bothering me!

Comment: try using overflow:auto in div style